# Oracle Join three tables: JOIN USING

Tags: oracle, join, plsql

I'm currently working through the Oracle DB Programming Modules and one of the questions is: Join DJs on Demand d_play_list_items, d_track_listings, and d_cds tables with the JOIN
USING syntax. Include the song ID, CD number, title, and comments in the output.

What I tried was several variations of this:

```
SELECT p.song_id, t.cd_number, c.title, p.comments
FROM d_play_list_items p JOIN d_track_listings t JOIN d_cds d
USING (song_id);
```

I keep getting the error message: ORA-00905: missing keyword
but I've got no idea what I'm doing wrong.

If someone could help me work through this I'd appreciate it a lot.

-Howie

Comment: You are missing an ON clause on the first joined table. Each table needs a full join clause.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest reading the [Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems).

Answer (score 3):

Each `JOIN` requires a corresponding `ON` or `USING` clause; in this case, given the requirements, a `USING` clause.

So you would need to add a `USING` clause for the first join:

```
FROM d_play_list_items p
JOIN d_track_listings t USING (?)
JOIN d_cds d USING (?)
```

It's not clear from your question exactly what the join columns should be in each case.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT 
Song_ID, 
CD_Number, 
Title, 
Comments 
FROM D_Play_List_Items p JOIN D_Track_Listings t 
USING (Song_Id) JOIN D_Cds d USING (Cd_Number);
```